# Passing in objects to GWT servlets via servlet attributes (server-side) or "Dependency Injection"

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat, servlets, dependency-injection

How do I pass objects from non-GWT server-side code (e.g. regular server code) to the GWT "servlet" (still server-side code), specifically a `RemoteServiceServlet`?

My GWT server-side code consists of RPC-type `RemoteServiceServlet`s to which I can't seem to get a reference so I can't pass in my real/fake object in testing mode or add servlet attributes. I can't see any way to simply pass objects in (dependency-injection style) as I have no access to the Server object as GWT seems to instantiate it deep within its internals, so what are my options?

P.S. I don't want to use a full-blown DI framework such as GIN/Juice - I find them to much magic. I just want a way to access the instance of a GWT servlet and pass stuff to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servlet containers are designed to not allow direct access to the servlets that they host; that's why you've found it difficult to get any kind of handle to a servlet.

Rather, refactor the code that is currently in your servlets into separate request-handler classes, and have your serlvets call into them.

For testing purposes you can hook your testing framework, or your client code, to the request-handler classes directly. That's how people generally solve the problem you've run into.

Comment: Hmm, on a normal Tomcat-like servlet container I can instantiate the servlets (or Handlers) myself (and then add them to the server ) which means I get a chance to hand them some global services. I'm looking for the same thing but for GWT servlets.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question so if a better answer comes along I will accept that instead

Answer (score 2):

Let me start out by saying, if you haven't already, I highly recommend watching [this Google I/O presentation on GWT Architecture best practices](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/GoogleWebToolkitBestPractices.html).  I found it very useful and it's where most of the following came from.

What I did was create an abstract "dispatch" servlet that extends GWT's RemoteServiceServlet.  Every module I have has only one service (that extends my abstract dispatch service) with which I register a set of request handlers.  All GWT service calls for a given GWT module come into that module's dispatch service, which looks at the type of request and dispatches it to the appropriate request handler.  The request handlers, in effect, handle the work that previously resided in the service servlet.  Besides making your life easier by having fewer servlets to register in your web.xml (not to mention avoiding the extra interfaces GWT requires), you can more easily control the dispatcher object that handles all the actual dispatching.  You can, for example, pass whatever real/mock object you like into these request handlers since you, and not the web container, are responsible for instantiating them.

And though I rolled my own, the [gwt-dispatch](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dispatch/) project exists for this very purpose.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't actually answer my question. What I  specifically want to know how to get a handle to any of my GWT servlets. They seem to exist in isolation, instantiated deep in the bowels of GWT and so I can't pass them anything.

Comment: The talk you linked to shows how to do client-side DI, but on the client-side I have an entry point so I can pass in anything I want to all my client-side code - it's the server-side that has no entry point where I can instantiate all my servlets and pass in whatever I like.

Comment: It doesn't directly give you exactly what you want, but the idea is to move the code you have in the GWT servlets into the request handlers. You can then manipulate these request handlers in the fashion that you want and not have to deal with the servlets (which is good, because the servlet container doesn't really allow you to get at them like you want anyway).

Comment: Also, I linked to that talk more because it has lots of good information that I think will be useful for all the people who read this question, more than for its direct relevance to your particular question.

Comment: These Handlers are also instantiated by the servlet container, right? So there's no way to grab a reference to them and pass them arguments at initialisation, or to get extra stuff passed in to the handlers as parameters, so I appear to be just as stuck with this approach.

Comment: No, the servlet container does not instantiate the request handlers.  Take a look at the gwt-dispatch documentation here (http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=gwt-dispatch&s=gwt-dispatch&t=GettingStarted) and scroll down to SimpleDispatchServlet.  If you look at the SimpleDispatchServlet constructor, you'll see the IncrementCounterHandler being instantiated.

Comment: You can instantiate handlers within a servlet, but that servlet itself is instantiatiated by GWT! In the link you gave, how would I pass a long-lives service object to SimpleDispatchServlet itself?

Comment: Are you using Spring or some other DI framework on the server side?  If not, do you have that long-lived service object in some repository from which you can pull it?  If so, then what I would do (what I am doing, in fact) is to pull my long-lived service objects out of Spring (inside my dispatch servlet constructor) and passing them off to the request handlers.  This dispatch servlet code doesn't really get anything passed to it, it has to go get everything it needs.

Comment: And while this is what you are technically trying to avoid, it becomes the only place where this is happening.  And to compensate for that, it moves code that you'd normally put inside the GWT servlet into a different place where you can inject/pass-in objects.